# Detect intersection between two svg shape

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, intersection

As part of a mobile application, I want to detect an intersection between an svg that is a circle and follow the user's finger and any imported svg shape. Here is an example of what I need (don't need all the points, only the value true or false):

[image]

I am using Ionic / Angular in Typescript. I have searched for several solutions but none of them seems to fit ...

How to achieve this?

Comment: perhafs this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972825/how-to-check-intersection-of-svg-elements) can help you -but you can only use one SVGRect (the "circle") and a SVG